# Check if an object's class is inherited from a specific sealed class

Tags: kotlin

I have a sealed class

```
sealed class Seal {
        object Type1
        object Type2
    }
```

and I would like to know an object is derived from "Seal"
e.g.

```
when (thing) {
    is Type1 -> {}//this returns true    
    is Seal -> {}//this returns false
}
```

is there a way to check if "Thing" is of type "Seal" instead of checking if it's "Type1" or "Type2"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Type1` and `Type2` are **not** of type `Seal`! To do so, you have to make them inherit the sealed class:

```
sealed class Seal {
    object Type1 : Seal()
    object Type2 : Seal()
}
```

And now both cases would be true:

```
when (thing) {
    is Type1 -> {}//this returns true    
    is Seal -> {}//this returns true    
}
```

More info at [kolin doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html#sealed-classes).